# Run time error in Xcode for having too many lines of code

Tags: iphone

I have written a large code (a calculator program) about 220,000 line of code and more in my base implementation file. The program build and run well, but whenever it comes to execute the codes from specific line number and further, the program stops, and gives a run time error. There is no problem with the code, I have tried it in smaller scale, (I mean deleting some lines) when it become smaller it runs ok. 
My question here is this, does the Xcode have limitation in capacity of each file when running? 
And if the answer is NO, so what should I do?

Comment: Not sure how to help you but, please break up that file. I've worked on large projects, and have never had files with greater than 1000 lines of code. It might be a big effort to do this, but it will do you (and future programmers) a world of good to have your code more modular.

Comment: Can you show the log and the code that crashs? I don't think there is such limit, because i got way larger projects.

Comment: Maybe it's not the number of lines, but you rather have a semantical error.

Comment: It could be Semantic Erros, better if you can show Errors description or Log.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was so confused and angry with my whole project, I eliminate some features from it, then it run fine, but now that I have upgrade my Xcode, my older code run just well, without any error, I think there was something wrong with my previous version of simulator.